# Javascript Array.prototype.filter unexpected output

Tags: javascript, arrays

### Background

Recently I was in a job interview, and someone made me a test:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
array[10] = 10;

alert(array.filter( n => n === undefined));
```

I was confident this was going to alert an array with 7x undefined, or something among those lines.

However, it outputs an empty array, as in an array of length 0.

### Question

For me this is perplexing. Can someone help me explain why this is happening ?

Comment: `var array = [1, 2, 3, undefined, undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,10];` would yield a filtered array because while they are a value of undefined, they are still declared. When you add a 10th index value, they are skipped (That's what a sparse array is, as Nina's good answer says).

Comment: JS functors won't traverse items at sparse indices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deleted or uninitialized (on sparse arrays) items are not visited.

[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description)

> **Description**
>
> `forEach()` executes the provided callback once for each element present in the array in ascending order. It is not invoked for index properties that have been deleted or are uninitialized (i.e. on sparse arrays).

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, , , , , , , , 10];

console.log(array.filter((n, i) => (console.log(i), n === undefined)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case knowing the internal helps, `Array.prototype.filter` (forEach, map, reduce as well) works sort like this(leaving out the boundary/corner checks):

```
Array.prototype.filter = function(fun/*, thisArg*/) {
    var arr = Object(this); 
    var len = arr.length;
    var res = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in arr) {
        var val = arr[i];

        if (fun.call(thisArg, val, i, arr)) {
          res.push(val);
        }
      }
    }

    return res;
}
```

The key is the `if` statement in the `for` loop:

```
if (i in arr) { ... }
```

It's clear for array items to be 'filterable', those items must be explicitly declared/initialized and have `key`/`prop` associated in the `arr`, which doesn't apply for the `sparse array` as pointed out by other answer.

<sub>note: if you run `var array = [1, 2, 3]; array[10] = 10;` in console, the resulting sparse array looks like this:</sub>

```
Array[11]
  0: 1
  1: 2
  2: 3
  10: 10
  length: 11
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Becaused the arrow function you set as the filter is returning only the items that are undefined, but none of your items are undefined, so the result is an empty array. But I think I know where you are getting confused.

```
array[10] = 10
```

doesn't set the length of the array. It sets a specific item to the value of 10. So after this line, you have an array with 4 elements: 1, 2, 3 and... 10.

In an array, you can set the index for a specific value. If you ommit it, it will just add 1 to the last index. Try this:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
array[10] = 10;

array.forEach( (value, index) => console.log(value, index));
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eetmkd95/1/

you'll see it prints this:

```
1 0 
2 1 
3 2 
10 10
```

why ? because if you don't specify the index it will generate one based on +1 increments, if you specify, then it will put your value in that index. But you are specifying the INDEX, not the length.
Now try this:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
array.length = 10;
array[8] = 10;

array.forEach( (value, ix) => console.log(value, ix));
console.log(array.length);
```

How can this be ? the length property is reporting 10 and the forEach only prints 4 lines ? that's because a) forEach only shows items that are actually present in the array and have number indexes and b) length isn't very trustable. It works only for number indexes and only if you don't set it to a higher value (it works if you set it to a lower value though). Also it doesn't work if you use strings as indexes. For example:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
array['myString'] =  10;

array.forEach( (value, ix) => console.log(value, ix));
console.log(array.length);
```

prints:

```
1 0
2 1
3 2
3
```

hope I clarified a bit :)

You can understand this in depth in the excelent book series "You don't know JS" from Kyle Simpson. The part that speaks about this is in "Types & Grammar" book, page 44, titled "Array(..)"

This may also be useful: http://www.2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html

Comment: no, arrow function has nothing to do with iterating undefined/spardes items, as well as setting an empty array an item with index 10, generates a length of 11.

Comment: you mean this`alert(array.filter( n => n === undefined));` has nothing to do with iterating undefined items ? it's filtering undefined items... maybe I couldn't understand what you meant. Can you explain better ? Also, about length, that only shows again that this property isn't very trustable, as I said.

Comment: there is no difference between arrow functions and classic functions. your mention of arrow function does not change the work of forEach with sparsed items.the other point is, the length is set by assigning a value to an item. if the index is equal or greater than the length property, the Array#length is set.

Comment: And this leaves us with a unreliable length don't you agree ? about the arrow function I was just pointing where in his code where this was happening, but I really think my language wasn't clear, have changed it. Hope it's better now.

Comment: i don't think that length un unreliable, because it needs defensive handling, like not to use delete and the knowledge, that `undefined` could be a value or a state.

Comment: I understand you view. But if length reports something and forEach loops function otherwise, I call this unreliable. Also there are tricks like `var a = Array.apply(null, Array(3))` and others, that further worsen the situation. I think Kyle Simpson's final of the array chapter of You don't know JS is clear enough: _"Bottom line: never ever, under any circumstances, should you intentionally create and use these exotic empty-slot arrays. Just don’t do
it. They’re nuts."_

Comment: @ Obviously, the length is *set* in sparse array, if you're not familiar with how sparse array works, `console` is your friend(books/best practices are good but not truth). As @NinaScholz pointed out `Deleted or uninitialized (on sparse arrays) items are not visited` is the key to this problem.

Comment: I know how it works, I just consider length unreliable because of the way it works. But anyway, I understand how you see it. :)